# Menu with fade effect

Tags: mootools

If you go to my website ([www.actemp.es](http://www.actemp.es/)) and you click on the menu button (right top), you'll see that the first time, the menu doesn't appear with fade, but other times yes. I want it to fade  even the first. I don't speak English very well =D

Here is my code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('in');
    });
});
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu2').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu2').fade('in');
    });
});
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu3').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu3').fade('in');
    });
});
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu4').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu4').fade('in');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why downvotes? OP and I would like to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mootools uses opacity to fade in and out. So add `opacity:0;` to your CSS (for `#menu`, `#menu2` & `#menu3` and it should work.)

I tried this on your page and worked. You can try this code also:
(you can anyway use CSS to fix this).

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    //this sets opacity to 0
    $('menu').setOpacity(0);
    $('menu2').setOpacity(0);
    $('menu3').setOpacity(0);
    $('menu4').setOpacity(0); // #menu4 is missing in the html
    //

    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('out');
        $('menu2').fade('out');
        $('menu3').fade('out');
        $('menu4').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('in');
        $('menu2').fade('in');
        $('menu3').fade('in');
        $('menu4').fade('in');
    });
});
```

**Btw:** You have a element missing in your code `#menu4`.

Comment: It's perfectly working!! Thanks so much!! Of course, I've recently deleted '#menu4'. =D

Answer (score -2):

First off, I don't think you need to separate the handlers into four blocks like that. The same `domready` event is being added, and the same two `click` events are being added. Try restructuring to this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('out');
        $('menu2').fade('out');
        $('menu3').fade('out');
        $('menu4').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('in');
        $('menu2').fade('in');
        $('menu3').fade('in');
        $('menu4').fade('in');
    });
});
```

See if this helps. My guess is the issue may lie with `window.addEvent('domready', function()`. This event fires very early on in the page loading sequence which may be a problem. Maybe try surrounding your code with the jQuery onLoad function instead:

```
$(function(){
    $('fadeout').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('out');
        $('menu2').fade('out');
        $('menu3').fade('out');
        $('menu4').fade('out');
    });
    $('fadein').addEvent('click', function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        $('menu').fade('in');
        $('menu2').fade('in');
        $('menu3').fade('in');
        $('menu4').fade('in');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is Mootools, no jQuery onLoad function please.